# handle multiple calls of rsync, dd and snapshot

Tags: centos, backup, rsync, snapshot, dd

The server runs the following operations often. It takes a snapshot of a logical volume, then backup up the content to the remote backup server. It is possible that multiple backups and transfer happen at the same time. Will too many rsync sessions and mounted snapshot volumes be a problem? How to optimize the server performance when handling?

```
lvcreate -L10G -s -n snapshot /home/folderA 

dd if=/mnt/snapshot bs=1M | (ssh root@192.168.1.5 of=/tmp/backups bs=1M)

rsync -avzh --rsh "ssh -l username" /mnt/snapshot 192.168.1.5:/tmp/backups/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably safest to put some sort of locking on these so that whichever is chosen only one instance runs at a time but without knowing how often you (plan to) run them and how long they take it's difficult to tell for sure.

CentOS has the [flock(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) command which would be useful.

> [ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0"
>          "$@" || :
>
> ```
>           This is useful boilerplate code for shell scripts.  Put it at
>           the top of the shell script you want to lock and it'll
>           automatically lock itself on the first run.  If the env var
>           $FLOCKER is not set to the shell script that is being run,
>           then execute flock and grab an exclusive non-blocking lock
>           (using the script itself as the lock file) before re-execing
>           itself with the right arguments.  It also sets the FLOCKER env
>           var to the right value so it doesn't run again.
> ```